# Create LINQ request

Tags: c#, linq

I have some collections:

`Dictionary<InvoceHeader, List<InvoiceHierarchy>>` where

```
public class InvoceHeader
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    public string DocumentDate { get; set; }
    public string DocumentReference { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceHierarchi
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string Certificate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I need to write a LINQ request to get such a collection from the original collection --> `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, where `key` --> `InvoceHeader.DocumentNumber`, `value` --> List two elements from `InvoiceHierarchi` such as the `SerialNumber` and `Certificate`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yeah that should be possible

Comment: Why you choose using `Dictionary` ?!

Comment: I get such an object at the input, and the task is to modify it to the final one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> converted = original
    .ToDictionary(
        kvp => kvp.Key.DocumentNumber,
        kvp => kvp.Value.Select(ih => ih.SerialNumber + ih.Certificate).ToList());
```

Comment: Note that, this can throw an ``exception`` if we have duplicated ``DocumentNumber``

Comment: @Sajid Yes good point, but that would probably be desirable as it would indicate an error in the input data.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<InvoceHeader> headers = new List<InvoceHeader>();
            List<InvoiceHierarchi> hierarchi = new List<InvoiceHierarchi>();

            var query = (from header in headers
                         join hierarch in hierarchi on header.DocumentNumber equals hierarch.Certificate
                         select new { header = header, hierarch = hierarch }
                         ).ToList();

            Dictionary<string, object> dict = query
                .GroupBy(x => x.header.DocumentNumber, y => new { header = y.header, hierachi = y.hierarch })
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => (object)y.ToList());

        }


    }
    public class InvoceHeader
    {
        public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
        public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
        public string DocumentDate { get; set; }
        public string DocumentReference { get; set; }
    }

    public class InvoiceHierarchi
    {
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string Certificate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be the query that you are looking for, only that you can replace the anonymous types that I am using in the query with a custom type that you created.

```
var newCollection = originalCollection.Select(x => new
                {
                    Key = x.Key.DocumentNumber,
                    Value = x.Value.Select(y => new
                    {
                        y.SerialNumber,
                        y.Certificate
                    }).ToList()
                });
```

If you want again to convert it to Dictionary, you can also add that line:

```
 var newDictionary = newCollection.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```